# Do Wii U Virtual Console discounts go off purchased games or games that are saved to the Wii system?

Tags: nintendo-wii, wii-u, virtual-console

I have transferred my Wii information to my Wii U and was wondering if I can delete the Virtual Console games I purchased on my Wii to save space. Or am I required to download the games and keep them on the Wii until they come to the Wii U Virtual Console to receive the discount?

Additionally, when getting games from Club Nintendo, can I put the code in and not download the games and still receive the discount later when they arrive onto the Wii U eShop? Meaning, the game is tied to my "account" and the download is not require. Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean in that last paragraph - the club nintendo games are download codes that get you free games, and will only be ones you can get for whatever system (they list the systems)

Comment: When you input the code into the wii shop it becomes apart of your account, after that you are given the option to download or exit the shop (with the game attached to your account to download later).

As noted below, Nolonar points out which I thought to be true that the download codes downloaded or not do link to your account and should affect the discount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to receive the discount when the game is not installed on the Wii part of your Wii U. I can confirm this, as I've been able to buy "A Link to the Past" at a lower price despite the game being on my SD card, rather than the console.

Because of that, we can safely assume that transfering your Wii data to your Wii U also links both console's accounts. Therefore you only need to have "purchased" the game to profit from the discount. Having the game installed on your console is not necessary.

Download codes, once redeemed, are considered the same as purchases. You should not need to actually download them to get the discount at a later point in time.

Should you for some reason not see the discounted price in the eShop, you can always boot up the Wii mode, download the games, then go back to the eShop. Games that have been purchased before can be downloaded as often as is needed for free, so that shouldn't be a problem at all.